# angular 2 complete user profile

Tags: angular

I'm a new with angular and want to make "improve user profile", the idea is make new component to fetch current user data and bring the empty one into this component to fill it, and so on...
for ex. if the user didn't fill his last name, the input field of last name will appear on that new component to be filled, after that will click save to save that and show the next.
for now I've use this to check if the data filled or not:

```
<div *ngIf="student.gender == NA" class="form-group data">
      <label>
          <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="student.gender"> Male
      </label>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="student.gender"> Female
      </label>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="student.birthdate == NA" class="form-group data">
      <form-date-picker [(ngModel)]="birthdate" [name]="'birthdate'" (newValue)="student.birthdate = $event" ></form-date-picker>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="student.nationality == NA" class="form-group data">
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="student.nationality" id="nationality" >
          <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>
          <option  *ngFor="let nationalityBean of nationalityBeans" value="{{nationalityBean.name}}" >{{nationalityBean.name}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>

<button class="btn btn-1uni btn-block" (click)="saveBasicData()" >Save</button>
```

the problem is:
I can't show only one field "to be like steps".
when I select gender the gender div disappeared without saving, until I click the save button.

So, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by create new variable to be like a bridge:
on component.ts file:

```
newGender: String;
```

on template.html:

```
<div *ngIf="student.gender === 'NA' || gender.dirty">
<!-- Gender will be "dirty" once you've interacted with the input field -->
  <input name="gender" [(ngModel)]="newGender" #gender="ngModel" >
</div>
```

and on submit method, just assign newGender to student.gender.

Answer (score 0):

It's only logical that the gender div disappears after you select a gender, because your expression is no longer true:

You're saying: if student.gender equals NA, then show the field.
However, when you're selecting a gender, student.gender is now no longer equal to NA, because it's "Male" or "Female".

A thing that you can do to solve this, is to use the functionality provided in @angular/forms.

EDIT: Removed the code example to avoid confusion. Use the snippet below.

Use the official documentation for more information: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective

**EDIT:
I forked your snippet and adjusted it to what you need: https://angular-48763586-f48k9q.stackblitz.io**

Comment: thanks @Roelof, but this not work with me
this error appear on console "Cannot read property 'dirty' of undefined"

Comment: Interesting... have you added #gender="ngModel" to both your gender radio input fields?

Comment: Yes:
  <div *ngIf="student.gender === 'NA' || gender.dirty" class="form-group data">
    {{gender.dirty}} <!-- this works good -->
      <label>
          <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender"  [(ngModel)]="student.gender" #gender="ngModel"> Male
      </label>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender"  [(ngModel)]="student.gender" #gender="ngModel"> Female
      </label>
  </div>

Comment: This is the code online: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48763586-6pdayw?file=app%2Fapp.component.html